# WebConfig url throw Forbidden error in Spring Boot Microservice (hasIpAddress issue)

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

In my Microservice example, I have a problem with my user service.
I used Spring Cloud API Gateway with its port number 8041

When I send a request to this URL (`http://localhost:8041/users-ws/users/status/check`) , I got a forbidden issue.

Here are my project folders shown below.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G2dRfHo8PpwQMqkZFJa8qHpYZnOuteIl?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Y7c5lbnSEeJ83mG33bSwRaa3R7ls5E1R?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d_rtpqnUm9wapkSD4n4hcwuZ7OmmrCIk?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1deh9-3Z-qLiIc1C_-EjDNriFEkSQ0p-T?usp=sharing

How can I fix it?

Here is my application.properties file

Here is my controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {


    // Load Balancer
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @GetMapping("/status/check")
    public String status(){
        return "Working on port " + env.getProperty("local.server.port");
    }
}
```

Here is my web config class shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    private Environment environment;
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public WebSecurity(Environment environment, UserService userService) {
        super();
        this.environment = environment;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
            .hasIpAddress(environment.getProperty("gateway.ip"))
            .and()
            .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter());
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception{
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(userService, environment, authenticationManager());
        //authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager()); 
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(environment.getProperty("login.url.path"));
        return authenticationFilter;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're only allowing requests from the IP in ```environment.getProperty("gateway.ip")``` in combination with the filter ```getAuthenticationFilter()```.

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk I defined my IP address in application.properties file but I got 403 error.